# Use AVR Atmega like a 555 for timer

Tags: atmega, programming, timer

I have a lot of AVR Atmega128P boards, and I would like to use it as timers **WITHOUT PROGRAMMING**, as example, just like 555 timers. Is it possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: You could program them ONCE to (e.g.) read voltages on analog pins and generate timing outputs - clocks, delays etc. Then you could "program" them in circuit by wiring up different resistances.

Comment: Most people start to use MCUs because they've migrated from 555s.

Answer (score 1):

No, without any (meaningful) program the MCUs don't do anything useful.

As Brian pointed out, you can definitely write a program that samples analog quantities (voltage on certain pins) and perform some tasks or generate digital outputs according to the read values. It might mimic 555 or do anything even more complex.

However, I'd say that mega128 are pretty much overkill for such task.